# Verifying an AEON transaction sent to cold storage

Tags: cold-storage, viewkey, aeon

How can I verify the receipt of AEON sent to cold storage?

Does AEON have a view key tool similar to this [XMR check transaction tool](http://xmrtests.llcoins.net/checktx.html) or this [Signed Outputs Public Keys Checker](https://explorer.xmr.my/rawoutputkeys) described in this [answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/957/162)?

Answer (score 1):

With stoffu’s rebased Aeon code, you could create a watch-only wallet with the view key, similar to Monero. Unless you also want to track outgoing transaction (which I think is unlikely for cold storage), this is quite a simple setup.