# Scanning of View only wallet with monejuro shows different balance

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, light-wallet, android-wallet, monejuro

I have setup a view only wallet using android monejuro wallet. I took the public key and the secret view key to make a view only wallet. However, this wallet is showing a different balance than my initial monero core wallet.

What could have gone wrong?

On the view wallet I see there is an extra transaction which I should not have received. this transaction does not show up on my monero core wallet with the full 30gb blockchain downloaded.

How can I fix this? Maybe I have to do a rescan?

Comment: It's probably change of a transaction that you sent out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View wallets only see incoming monero, not outgoing monero. In order to know outgoing ones (and thus see the balance), you need to import key images from the full wallet (the one with the spend keys).

See [How can I check the balance of a Monero paper wallet?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4179/how-can-i-check-the-balance-of-a-monero-paper-wallet/4227#4227) for instructions.

Comment: I did send 1 xmr to another address. could that be why the view only wallet is seeing these extra coins received?

Comment: What do you mean by key images? You mean the private view and spend keys? or just the public view and spend keys? The monejuro app only lets me add a "View Key" and "Public Address" only. Wouldn't this view only feature be flawed as you can only see coins received? Hence throwing your balance off as you get change back.

Comment: By key images, I mean key images. Had you ready what I linked above, you would have seen them explained. I will not repeat myself.