# Simple website to check Monero balance

Tags: mymonero, viewkey, balance, view-only, web-wallet

Similar questions have been asked often, but no satisfying answer so far...

Is it possible to (*read-only*) check the balance of a **Monero** address with only providing the address and ViewKey (no `Payment Id` or `SpendKey` or whatever), and without first installing/syncing software for it?

Just a simple web interface for this?

Something like `mymonero.com` would be nice, but for the login on it, you always have to provide the `SpendKey` as well (or the `LoginKey`), which makes it risky to lose the funds.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to (readonly) check the balance of a Monero address with only providing the address and ViewKey (no Payment Id or SpendKey or whatever), and without first installing/syncing software for it? Just a simple web interface for this?

Yes, that's possible

#### Private wallet

For a private wallet, turns out this is really a good question! I don't have an answer for you but maybe this post will help you: [How can I check the balance of a Monero paper wallet?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/4179/how-can-i-check-the-balance-of-a-monero-paper-wallet/4598)

#### exchange wallet:

A very easy way would be to grab an API of some exchange (for example Binance), have your funds there and by accessing a website you can check the balance of your wallet.

So since an exchange gives you access to your balance, you could easily use that to show that balance somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
I actually didn't mean an exchange account, but a personal monero address. Everyone tells you that you never should keep your Coins on an exchange, because not under your personal control. I actually lost quite a lot thru a hacked exchange, so this idea totally makes sense to me.
So there is no simple way to look up a Monero addresse's balance without having write access at the address?
Like e.g. etherscan.io for ethereum?

Comment: You're right. It's better to have your coins in your own wallet. I'm pretty sure there is a simple way to get your wallet balance. I will look it up and let you know another solution :)