# Workflow of basic operations in the CLI

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, cold-storage, balance, transfer, cli

I am new to Monero and I am looking forward to understand better how to use it on the CLI so I can send donations to the wallet and have my uncle be able to use those in Venezuela due to the nonsense going on there.

I am comfortable with my current knowledge of asymmetric cryptography and Linux. I would like to use the CLI for basic operations on a paper wallet I generated offline.

I have the data of the paper wallet: public address, private view key, private spend key and so forth. I sent a little amount just for testing purposes and I got the hash transaction ID.

Ideally I would like to be able to perform the basic operations on that wallet on my computer via CLI:

- Restore the wallet
- Check the balance
- Make a transfer payment

So far what I did was:

```
pacman -Sy monero                  # Install monero on Arch
sudo systemctl start monerod       # Start the daemon and sync the blockchain
monero-wallet-cli --generate-from-keys mywallet.monero
# It will prompt for public address, secret spend key and secret view key

# Then I exit the prompt and start again with
monero-wallet-cli
# It will prompt for the wallet and password
# Then I check the transaction hash id with:
get_tx_key e13e...
```

At that point it gets confusing since I keep getting the following: `Error: no tx keys found for this txid`.

I tried also `balance` command but it always shows 0. From what I have read I need to keep track of the txid's an individual key for each transaction so I can then use the `check_tx_key` command. I assume that every time I run that command the wallet will know that transaction is claimed and therefore update the wallet (but I might be wrong here).

After that I would like to be able to perform a transfer on the CLI, but I couldn't even get to that point since I cannot even check the balance.

I have seen some post about it like [this one using the CUI](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/4227) and [this official tutorial](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/monero-wallet-cli.html) but I am not able to reproduce it.

It might be the case that the blockchain is not fully downloaded. I have no idea on how much would be the size and time needed for this. Or if it is an API based service. Just for the sake of completion I started the service about an hour ago. Maybe I am doing something wrong to restore the paper wallet, I am not sure.

Could anyone please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> `get_tx_key e13e...`
>
> At that point it gets confusing since I keep getting the following: Error: no tx keys found for this txid.

`get_tx_key` is used to obtain the tx private key on the *sending* wallet, not the receiving wallet.

> I tried also balance command but it always shows 0 ... It might be the case that the blockchain is not fully downloaded.

Until you've fully sync'ed and scanned the blockchain, your balance (on a new wallet, and until it's been sent funds), will be [zero](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/i-am-missing-not-seeing-a-transaction-to-in-the-gui-zero-balance).

> Just for the sake of completion I started the service about an hour ago

With a half decent internet connection and syncing to an SSD, it should take well under a day.