# How to use the CLI without syncing the full node data?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization, balance, transfer, cli

This is a [followup question of this one](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/13879/workflow-of-basic-operations-in-the-cli). I would like to perform basic CLI operations without having to download +100GB of data.

How are you checking on a transfer, balances "safely" without having to run your own node? I would prefer the CLI if possible, but GUI would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a remote node with the CLI wallets. See options `--daemon-*`.

The GUI wallet also allows you to use a remote node, as do most mobile wallets.

Now, "safely" here is subjective, running your own node (locally or remotely) is *always* better than trusting someone else's.